# Problems with software layers in complex query methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, api-design, layers

I designed a rest api software with 2 simple layers: `Controller` and `Service`. The controller handles the coming http request and redirect to a service method. In the beginning of development every was going well with the standards CRUDs. The problems now is the complex reporting query.

For each persistence entity I create a typed service and controller.

E.g.: A `Person` class has a `PersonService` the is called by a `PersonController`.

To achieve the report task, I've been creating lots of query methods and put the data to a DTO's and manipulate the data using them. The report data needs a lot of calculation and comparison with another tables data and I'm basically doing that calculation in DTO's because I don't want to query my complete domain object to work with 2 or 3 fields.

My service layer grew up a lot with all that query methods and I know that I'm doing a wrong thing to handle state of data inside DTO before expose them, but how could I fix that with a simple solution? I decided to create a few layers to make the things simple and now I'm not sure if I made the right decision.

Comment: I think this is very hard to answer in a sensible manner, without seeing a more concrete example of how your domain model looks like and why you think it is a problem to query domain objects completely.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't want to query my complete domain object to work with 2 or 3 fields.

Of everything you've said, this frightens me the most.

The domain exists to get something done. If you've creating something that won't let you pull "2 or 3 fields" into a domain object easily you've crippled yourself.

Now if those "2 or 3 fields" exist in `Person` I can imagine why you're reluctant. A `Person` class can easily become a monster. You slay that monster by breaking it into little monsters like `Address`.

What your "2 or 3 fields" really need is a good name to hide behind. Coming up with that name should be the most difficult part. If the most difficult part is actually supporting this new domain thing then your other layers are way too coupled to your domain.

I suspect that's an issue because you have mentioned classes like `PersonService` and `PersonController`. Now it's good to have many small services and controllers, but it's not good to set up 1 to 1 relationships between them and the domain objects. If you do that there's no point in having separate layers. Each layer needs its own idea of what it's up to and the scope in which it works. And that means it's objects need their own names.

Do that and you should find you can whip up a new domain object about as quickly as you can think of its name.